How do I make my discord bot not showing Playing, Watching, Streaming, etc when displaying a status message?
Python lines:
status_message = "Hello World"

await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name=status_message))

It's currently showing:
Watching Hello World

Is there a way to just show, Hello World.

This question is similar to: Discord.py How do I make my bot have a custom status. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I found this trick. Credit to this person. It works.
Discord.py How do I make my bot have a custom status
await client.change_presence(
    activity=discord.Activity(
        type=discord.ActivityType.custom, name="custom", state=status_message
    )
)


You can use discord.CustomActivity(), which is equivalent to discord.ActivityType.custom
my_message = "Hello world!"
activity = discord.CustomActivity(name=my_message)
await client.change_presence(activity=activity)

Documentation Reference
